# Can a linearly independent set of vectors have more elements than its dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a basic theory question, but it has me stuck regardless (partially because of wording)

The question is:

**Every linearly independent set of vectors in R6 has 6 or more elements: True or False**

My assumption was that in R6 you can have at maximum 6 linearly independent vectors. I would assume this true if it said only 6, but the or more has me stuck. I've looked at multiple resources but I'm not having much luck looking for the answer. Any answer helps, I'm mostly looking for understanding. Thanks!

Comment: No. For instance a set consisting of a single nonzero vector is linearly independent.

Comment: The sentence is badly formed and I hate this kind of puzzle-like questions. A question to test if students have understood or not the concept is "What is the maximum number of  linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^6$?  As a teacher I try to formulate question and not riddles...

Comment: A true statement would be “every linearly independent set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^6$ has six or less elements”.

Comment: Or "Seven or more distinct vectors in $\mathbb{R}^6$ are always linearly dependent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording is clear: the statement is

> if $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ (with $v_i\ne v_j$ for $i\ne j$) is linearly independent, then $k\ge6$.

The statement is false: indeed the set consisting of a single nonzero vector is linearly independent.

<sup>Also the empty set, having zero elements, qualifies, of course.</sup>

Some true statements.

1. In any vector space, given $k>0$ there exists a linearly *dependent* set having $k$ elements.
2. In a vector space of dimension $n$, any set with more than $n$ elements is linearly dependent
3. In a vector space of dimension $n$, a linearly independent set has at most $n$ elements.

In order to prove 1, if $1<k\le n$, consider a linearly independent set having $k-1$ elements (it certainly exists) and add to it the sum of the elements. For $k>n$, apply 2. For $k=1$, take the set consisting of the zero vector.

Comment: Also true: Any set of vectors in $\mathbb R^6$ that spans $\mathbb R^6$ has $6$ or more elements.